# Load Data to Google Map API

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary

i need to read lat and LNG and other parameter from text file on desktop to my google map java script API for my project in university .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using  [HTML5 FileAPI](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/). But it is neccessary, that u or user should select the file for reading. After uploading file, remains only to parse the necessary variables in the correct manner. Short example:

```js
function readSingleFile(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    displayContents(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML = contents;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
<pre id="file-content"></pre>
```